# Is it normal to have this long fall time with a MOSFET and a LED strip at 100Hz?

Tags: led, mosfet

I'm using the following schematic to drive a LED strip (15 LED) with a MOSFET from an arduino PWM :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIoebQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But when I check the tension at the LED strip (between NODE1 and NODE2) with a 100Hz PWM, I have the following signal :

[image]

Do you know what would cause this long fall time ? I've checked the input PWM, the square signal is ok. Is it for the same reason as in this question (ie. the scope probe) : [MOSFET fall time too slow](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/27135/129361) ?

Comment: Could be you are just seeing the dynamic resistance of the diodes changing as the Vf across them drops.

Comment: It may also be some parasitic capacitance. That takes some time, could you specify exactly where you measure in the schematic?

Comment: To ground or across the LED?

Comment: How long is the ground wire of your oscilloscope probe, please inform us with more details about how you measured your results and your test setup.

Comment: Look at your gate drive signal first.  Then check the actual drain of the MOSFET.  Likely your gate drive is weak.

Comment: Don't forget that below a certain voltage the LEDs will effectively stop conducting, so there's nothing pulling the voltage all the way to 0. Try throwing a power resistor in parallel with your led strip and see if this goes away.

Comment: Where on the schematic are your voltage probes?

Comment: Thanks for your propositions. I quickly added the location of my measurement on the schematic. To measure I use a pocket scope (https://www.seeedstudio.com/DSO-Nano-v3-p-1358.html), but I get the same signal with another one. I will also update my question with pictures of my setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I would have guessed, you're measuring across the LED/resistor. Be aware that the LED (when it goes out, as the voltage falls below its conduction voltage) becomes a very high resistance. This, is conjunction with the FET's drain capacitance, forms an R-C circuit with a rather long time constant.

Which is exactly what you're seeing.

Indeed you can pretty much identify the voltage at which the LED is fully off from the point where the negative edge ceases to be vertical.

So, for the circuit as revised, yes this is normal.

Put something like 10 kilohms across the LED, and you'll see a much cleaner waveform, as an experiment. (Leave it there if you like, it won't waste much power, but that long fall time isn't doing any harm)

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try this ! And so for curiosity, based on the mosfet datasheet and the scope graph, I could estimate the internal resistance of the blocking LED ?

Comment: I finally took time to test the schematic with a resistance across the LED, and as expected it worked :). Thank you !