# Whats is the relation between long MOSFET Turn-Off time and oscilloscope probe capacitance

Tags: mosfet, oscilloscope, capacitance

I have a tri-state MOSFET array to control a 12V charliplexed led matrix. My question is that in the oscilloscope I see that the PMOS has an off curve that does not make sense to me, searching the forum I came to this [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/27135/mosfet-fall-time-too-slow), which states that the capacitance of the oscilloscope probes should be the cause. However, I do not understand how that happens and how can I do to verify if indeed the PMOS is shutting down as fast as I expect, I'm trying to avoid a shoot-through situation.

The MOSFET array is a [DMC2400UV](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DMC2400UV.pdf). The Turn-off Delay time is 13.74 ns and Turn-off Fall time is 10.54 ns.

Schematic of the MOSFETS array, the whole system is composed of 9 of these.
[image]

For the oscilloscope images: Yellow is OUT1, Blue is PMOS1 and Pink is a HIGH-Z port (might be Out3)

Effect at 1ms switching time

[image]

Effect at 20ms switching time

[image]

Comment: How the probe capacitance affects things will depend on the probe you're using. What probe is it?

Comment: Tektronix P2220 https://www.tek.com/datasheet/passive-voltage-probe-1x-10x

Comment: 10k is way too high to discharge those gates quickly. I'd look for a dual-gate driver IC; that would eliminate 1 PMOS and 3 resistors. (Would also require a bypass capacitor.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely cause is the parasitic capacity of transistor's gate.
Probe capacity may have some effect, but I doubt it is significant.

When you change gate voltage to high, the parasitic capacity of transistor's gate is charged directly from the input (which seems to deliver sufficient current) so the voltage changes fast.

On the other hand, when you switch input low, parasitic capacity is discharged through a resistor.

Voltage changes according to equation:
$$V=V_{high}\cdot e^{-\frac{t}{RC}}$$

\$R\$ is the resistor and \$C\$ the parasitic capacity at the gate.
\$RC\$ is called the time constant \$\tau\$ and it has a dimension of time (unit of seconds if \$R\$ is in \$\Omega\$ and \$C\$ in F).

At \$t=\tau\$, the voltage at gate equals \$V=V_{high}\cdot e^{-1}=37 \% \cdot V_{high}\$

Sufficient time for discharging is some multiple of \$\tau\$, eg at \$5\tau\$ it gets to \$0.7 \%\$.

To make the falling edge steeper, you need to decrease \$\tau\$, which is best achievable by decreasing \$R\$.

For power MOSFETs that should switch rapidly, you can use MOSFET-driver circuits, which are used to deliver high current for fast switching. (required current may be too high even for directly connecting to GPIO pin, let alone pull-down resistor).

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply.The problem I have to implement MOSFET drivers is the size, my application is extremely small, that's why my packages are SOT-563 and SOT-963. 

The equations are very useful, however I still have the problem of ending up with a strong pull-up or pull-down, so in that sense I can't lower the resistance much. so far all of them are 10Kohm.